# How to stop Smarty template from outputting all HTML on one line?

Tags: php, templates, smarty

I've recently been hired to work on some PHP and the current system they have in place is using smarty.

The only problem I seem to be having is smarty is outputting all the HTML onto one line, which is hurting when I'm trying to debug in browser and all the references refer to "line 1".

I've tried unregistering the trimwhitespace outputfilter , deleting the cached files and force a recompile, no luck.

Answer (score 2):

You've provided no code at all, so this is only a wild guess.

Check the template files if there is excessive use of the Smarty function [`{strip}`](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.strip.tpl), because

> Anything within `{strip}{/strip}` tags are stripped of the extra spaces
>   or carriage returns at the beginnings and ends of the lines before
>   they are displayed.

But as said, this is only a wild guess targeting a Smarty specific cause. There are numerous other ways to generate such a compressed html output.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but these tags didn't exist anywhere, and  I even tested it by creating an entirely new file and rendering to smarty, still got the one liner. Eventually I upgraded smarty (they were using an old version) and presto, everything works fine now.